# Ember - computed property not firing/updating

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an array controller where I want a value that will indicate which item in the array has been selected in the UI.  I've modelled what I'm doing after this post:

https://teamgaslight.com/blog/intermediate-ember-controller-concepts

Seems pretty simple, but in my app, I am using the {{render}} helper.  The render helper is due to having multiple lists similar to this one

The problem is that when I click on the list item, the appropriate actions fires and updates the correct field on the array controller, but the item controllers' computed property is not updating/firing.

here is a JSBin that illustrates my issue (note that you'll need to click on the 'states' item to reveal the list of states):

http://jsbin.com/fucaqe/1/

I used the render helper because in the actual app, there are three lists similar to this in the same area and breaking each list seemed to be the best way to organize the code and keep my sanity :-)

Things I've verified:

- the 'needs' property is set up correctly on the item controller
- the .property() on the item controller is pointing to the correct field on the array controller
- Answers to similar questions on SO have not adequately resolved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use needs on a controller that isn't a singleton, and controllers that aren't singletons won't make sense (such as item controller items).

Additionally computed properties aren't computed unless something tries to get them.

Example: http://jsbin.com/zevuzo/1/edit

http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Comment: On the State Object controller, there is the 'isSelected' computed property which is accessed on the template via {{bind-attr}}.  That's the property that isn't updating like I expect.  I see what you did to get the state name to show and the helps, but the isSelected part is more troubling.

Comment: Also, is there any documentation that describes when needs will and won't work?  The guides and docs on emberjs.com make no indication that the 'needs' property doesn't work in some cases

Comment: I was referring to the selectedStateName, which means I misunderstood your question.  I updated the answer, you should use parentController when you are using an itemController

Comment: aha! that was it.  I may not have been clear on which property was giving me headaches either.  I've read that link you added before and again just now. It doesn't seem to say when 'needs' won't work, just to use it for managing dependencies between controllers.  Thx for the help!